# Spring Integration benchmark

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, jms, spring-integration

I would like to know if anyone has any experiences with Spring Integration framework as it's messaging provider?

I couldn't find any benchmarks or details.

Would like to know details concerned to latency,throughput,performance.

Anyone has any experience?

Thanks.

Comment: adding spring-integration tag

Comment: May be suresh manda's link useful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't provide any official benchmark-based numbers, but we've been using Spring Integration (with JMS broker in the middle) as an underlying framework for two of our products serving HTTP traffic where latency and throughput were also the most important factors. Both proved their reliability under really heavy load - standing in the first line (just after load balancer) in the infrastructure of some top European e-commerce sites -  no lags, no unexpected fails, great scalability. Of course everything depends on how you design flow in channels, but basis on my previous experience, if I had to develop similar solution once again, I'd definitely go to Spring Integration.

Answer (score 1):

As with any framework, there will be some minimal runtime overhead, but that is vastly outweighed by the resulting loosely coupled, agile, robust architecture and the (often) reduced development time.

Comment: yes those are the reasons why I am considering that framework but in other hand I am design trading system. latency and throughput are huge factors in our considerations.